# Error when using Firebase Auth on a cloud function with Zeit Now

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, next.js, vercel

I'm using Nextjs and deploying it with Zeit now.

I'm trying to implement session management using Firebase auth and what I'm trying to do is to set cookies on the user's request. I have the following function:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
// Initializing firebase admin
import admin from '../../helpers/firebase/init';
const db = admin.firestore();
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    // ...
    const sessionCookieRxpiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    const sessionCookie = await admin
      .auth()
      .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn: sessionCookieRxpiresIn });
    res.setHeader(
      'Set-Cookie',
      `session=${sessionCookie};Max-Age=${sessionCookieRxpiresIn};HttpOnly;Path=/`,
    );
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
  }
};
export default handler;
```

This function works just fine locally with `now dev`, but when I'm deploying it to now, I see the following error after invoking this function `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google/protobuf/api.proto'`.

I didn't find any valuable advice on the internet to help me deal with this issue. Any advice?